# Two onclick Events with One Button

Tags: html, onclick

I have a button like below:

```
    <a href="{{ relatedEntry.url }}" data-target="http://go.redirectingat.com/?id=120996X1581244&url={{ affiliateLink|url_encode }}&sref={{ entry.url|url_encode }}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-voucher btn-lg btn-block popunder" onclick="$.popunder(this);">
      Reveal Code & Visit<i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>
    </a>
```

But I'm trying to add a Google event tracking code as well within this button:

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Deal', 'Deal Click');"
```

I've added both, but this seems to break the popunder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger 2 or more functions on a trigger, separated by semicolons.

Here is a quick prototype where a button click will call two separate functions:

```
<button onclick="a();b();">Double Action</button>
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

javascript functions:

```
function a(){
    document.getElementById('a').innerHTML ='A';
}
function b(){
    document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = 'B';
}
```

here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89s2wkny/)

The only catch is that the first function does not cause an action that prevents calling or processing of the next function(s). Like redirect url, or fatal exception.

Comment: This was really helpful! Thank you!